# .NET 8 - Migrating from PrintDocument to Microsoft.Maui.Graphics

Tags: printing, asp.net-core-webapi, maui, .net-8.0

I'm building an `ASP.NET Core 8 Web API`.

I'm trying to migrate a functionality from `.NET Framework 4.5.1` to my API.
I used to use the `PrintDocument` class to print a test page.
The compiler warns me that my API is multiplatform and the `PrintDocument` is Windows Specific.

Following the [link of the compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only) I ended up reading the "[Recommended Action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#recommended-action)" section where the `Microsoft.Maui.Graphics` is suggested as a crossplatform solution.

But when looking online, I can only find people stating that there's no printing functionality in the Maui framework.

I'd like to know what Microsoft meant when they suggested to migrate to Maui regarding crossplatform printing ?

Could anyone provide a POC ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print in .NET Maui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76685032/how-to-print-in-net-maui)

Comment: I read that post, but the only valuable answer suggest native code approach. While this may be the only current solution, I was expecting a more high level/standard solution.

Comment: I doubt you’ll find one.  Each platform has very different printing APIs, and in my experience the need to print from mobile apps is not that common

Comment: @Jason As far as I can see OP does not need to print from mobile app but from an ASP.NET Core one. The mobile APIs were planned  to be used as substitute for Windows ones used by the .NET Framework version of the app.

Comment: From what I can see - you can create platform specific implementation for printing, on Windows  still using `PrintDocument` and on linux leveraging [`lpr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lpr.1.html) CLI command.

Comment: How your app will be deployed? On Windows or on Linux?

Comment: @Guru Stron, You are right, the idea was to print on the server side. This is because the API is an intranet API. The server is a windows server which is why I added the following attribute on my method : [SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]. But we have different types of server and some have access to different printers and will require the same feature. My current solution is to implement platform specific printing. It's working ofc, but I was looking for something cross-platform

Comment: @AxelSamyn have not worked much with printing so can't suggest out of the box cross-platform solution (if any exists at all). If you'll find one - please share.